# Set correct height for tableView in ScrollView

Tags: uitableview, tableview, height, scrollview

I have some content (title, image, description) in a ScrollView which works, and I now have to implement a comments list after the description.
To do this, I'm using a TableView with custom cells (though I'm open to other choices) which I believe I've correctly set up, and it adds my content and my comments shows correctly.

I would like to display all of the rows (regardless of the number) one by one at the bottom of my view, and disable the scrolling possibility on my table View, but I have not been successful.

I've tried unchecked the "Scrolling Enabled" item in the Attribute inspector but I don't know the right way to set the height of my TableView to 100% of all my rows.

In addition, the rows are actually dynamic as they may have multiple lines (small row for a tiny comment and height row for a long one).
Finally, my ScrollView doesn't show me my table view if I don't set to this last one a height constraint.

I'm open to code again all of this part if you have a better solution for me.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: is your `tableView` height dynamic or not? and why are you puting 'tableView` in `scrollView`? add your code and output screenshot so we can understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: It would be a bad idea to try to show 500 rows of a table view, for many reasons. Instead of embedding these elements in a scroll view, what you probably want to do is put your *"(title, image, description)"* in the table header view, and simply use the table view as normal.